# Repeat "Have a nice day" as many times as user requests in clojure

Tags: java, syntax, clojure

After having Java experience I wanted to try my hand in Clojure. Obviously a lot of the syntax is different but let's say I wanted to create a program where it would output "Good morning" as many times as the user requests. For example, the user would type in "8" into the command line and the program would output "Good morning" 8 times. Now in Java this can be done with a simple for statement and an iterative loop with something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)    
 {    
 System.out.println("Good morning"); 
 }
```

You use the scanner for Java and the readline() command for Clojure, but what about for the loop? I'd appreciate any help, been googling for awhile.

Comment: There are many ways to "loop" in a functional language. The general idea is to think of your problem in terms of transformations, and leaving the printing until the very end. Here you have two arguments, a number and a message. The `repeat` function (as shown in an answer) shows how you can use those arguments to get a list of messages. Then you're ready to print. The two major ways to "loop" is to use recursion, or to use a function that does the recursion for you. Check out the `for` and `doseq` functions, and figure out how they differ. Also try using recursion.

Comment: `readline()` is not Clojure. The function is called `read-line` and `f()` is not valid clojure syntax for calling a function.

Answer (score 3):

```
(dotimes [_ (read)] (println "Good Morning"))
```

This reads a number, and prints "Good Morning" that many times.

There will be an error if the input typed in is not readable as a number.

Clojure is more interesting when it comes to pure functions on immutable inputs, and various ways of creating transformed versions of data structures. But this is likely the clearest way to do some action N times when you don't care about what the function returns.

Comment: more direct translation of the original: `(dotimes [i (read)] (println "Good Morning"))`

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the reference for [`doseq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq) and [`repeat`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/repeat).

Also, the [ClojureDocs QuickRef](http://clojuredocs.org/quickref/clojure%20core) is a great resource in general.

```
(doseq [x (repeat 10 "Good Morning")] 
  (println x))
```

In the above example, `repeat` creates a lazy sequence of `10` `"Good Morning"` strings. `doseq` acts like the actual `for` loop and forces the evaluation of the lazy sequence, each time binding `x` to the next element of the sequence.